# Is it possible to perform different actions in a Cucumber step based on the tag used (or not)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I use the same step in various placed throughout my cucumber testing. I would like to make a minor change based on whether or not the calling feature has a tag assigned (in this case @javascript).

Is it possible to test for the presence and name of a tag within a step to change the behaviour? (I realise I could just create different steps, but that's not very DRY is it?)

Pseudo code to explain what I'm after

```
When /^I sign in as "(.*)\/(.*)"$/ do |email,password|
  step %{I go to the sign in page}
  step %{I fill in "user_email" with "#{email}"}
  step %{I fill in "user_password" with "#{password}"}

  if tag && tag == "@javascript"
    step %{I follow "LOG IN"}
  else
    step %{I press "LOG IN"}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got around this by using hooks to set variables, which may be useful if your tag isn't associated with a driver:

```
Before('@mobile') do
    @mobile = true
end

When /^I go to the homepage$/ do
    if @mobile
        visit "m.mysite.com"
    else
        visit "www.mysite.com"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can directly access the tags from within the step defs easily, but you can access the current driver:

```
Capybara.current_driver
```

So assuming you use a different driver for your @javascript tagged scenarios, this should work.