# With Capybara, how can I tell whether the driver currently being used supports JavaScript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

In my Rails application, I have a set of cucumber acceptance tests that test various pages of my application. With cucumber, tagging a specific test (scenario) with `@javascript` causes that scenario to run using a JavaScript driver instead of a simpler driver that does not support JavaScript.

Is there an easy way for my tests to determine whether they are currently being run with a driver that supports JavaScript or one that doesn't? I want this so that I can make my tests behave slightly differently if they are being run with JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In case anyone's interested, I took a look at the [documentation for Capybara](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/frames) and found another possible solution:

```
if Capybara.current_driver == Capybara.javascript_driver
  # Supports JavaScript
else
  # Doesn't support JavaScript
end
```

Comment: This is OK except when your javascript_driver is (say) poltergeist, but your specific example is actually using selenium

Comment: It won't work if you use several JS drivers like me (selenium & poltergeist)

Answer (score 7):

It's kind of obnoxious, but this is what I landed on.  Think I got it from a gist somewhere, sorry I lost the link to it but at least it's pretty straightforward:

```
def javascript_test?
  [:selenium, :webkit, :chrome, :poltergeist].include?(Capybara.current_driver)
end
```

If you define (or require in your Gemfile) other js enabled drivers, you'd have to add them to this list.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492800/is-it-possible-to-perform-different-actions-in-a-cucumber-step-based-on-the-tag) like the easiest way to do this is to set an instance variable in a `Before` hook:

```
Before('@javascript') do
  @javascript = true
end
```

Then you can test if a scenario is tagged in step definitions by checking the value of that instance variable:

```
When /^I go to the homepage$/ do
  if @javascript
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

I've tested this and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply probe for the capability and rescue any exception. This is probably the most precise and compatible approach:

```
def support_js?
  return @support_js unless @support.nil?
  @support_js = begin
    page.evaluate_script("1 + 1")
    true
  rescue Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError => _err
    false
  end
end
```